# ggplot2: group x axis discrete values into subgroups

Tags: r, ggplot2, grouping

I would like to create a bar plot with ggplot2 in which the discrete values of the x axis would be grouped into subgroups (see picture attached - the picture is from the web I do not have a code for the plot yet).

[image]

Thanks for your help !

Comment: have you tried to `facet_wrap` by group?

Comment: From what I read about facet_wrap, it would split the plot in n number of columns/rows...

Comment: you can always use `facet_grid` to control the facet layout.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Two approaches:

Example data:

```
dat <- data.frame(value=runif(26)*10,
                  grouping=c(rep("Group 1",10),
                             rep("Group 2",10),
                             rep("Group 3",6)),
                  letters=LETTERS[1:26])

head(dat)
     value grouping letters
1 8.316451  Group 1       A
2 9.768578  Group 1       B
3 4.896294  Group 1       C
4 2.004545  Group 1       D
5 4.905058  Group 1       E
6 8.997713  Group 1       F
```

Without facetting:

```
ggplot(dat, aes(grouping, value, fill=letters, label = letters)) + 
     geom_bar(position="dodge", stat="identity") + 
     geom_text(position = position_dodge(width = 1), aes(x=grouping, y=0))
```

With facetting:

```
ggplot(dat, aes(letters,value, label = letters)) + 
     geom_bar(stat="identity") + 
     facet_wrap(~grouping, scales="free")
```

Facetting has the obvious advantage of not having to muck about with the positioning of the labels.

Comment: Thanks ! It looks pretty good with facetting. However, is it possible to get the same width for all the bars independently of the numbers of values I have for each group?(when using scales="free_x", the width of the groups is the same but not the bars. When using scales="free_y", that's the opposite).

Comment: Found it. I used `facet_grid` with the argument 'space="free_x"` !

Comment: How would you do this on the y axis with discrete, non-numberical values ?

Answer (score 9):

To pile on an alternative, there is also `ggh4x::guide_axis_nested()`, which solves a similar issue. Disclaimer: I'm the author of ggh4x.

```r
library(ggplot2)

df <- data.frame(
  x = LETTERS[1:16],
  group = rep(c("Group 1", "Group 2", "Group 3"), c(5, 3, 8)),
  value = rpois(16, 10)
)

ggplot(df, aes(paste0(x, "&", group), value)) +
  geom_col() +
  guides(x = ggh4x::guide_axis_nested(delim = "&"))
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2023-02-24 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>

Comment: I get an unexpected cluster behavior if I use your exact example but set:  x= LETTERS[1:2].   
    I would LIKE for it to look identical to what you have above but every group just has letters A and B. Unfortuntely, when I do that it no longer groups by "group" and instead spits by groups across A and B.  Any way to fix that?

Comment: You can do `factor(paste(...), levels = ...)` to set the levels in the order that you want.

Comment: I'll create a new post :) Still having trouble making it look like above.the "Group" still isn't visually looking like what you have above.