# How to place the strip in facet_grid on top of plots when plotting graphs vertically stacked - similar to position.strip = "top" in facet_wrap?

Tags: r, ggplot2, facet-wrap, facet-grid

Using `facet_grid()`, how can I place the group names, i.e. the grey strips, on the top of the plots when graphing the plots stacked vertically in a single column?

From what I have tried, when stacking the plots vertically, using `facet_grid()`, you cannot place the strip on the top or bottom of the graph; you can only place the strip on the right hand side or the left hand side of the plots using the `switch = c("y", "x", "both")` argument.

I am aware that `facet_wrap()` (and `facet_col()` from ggforce) can place the strip anywhere using the `strip.position = c("top", "bottom", "left", "right")` argument, irrespective of how the graphs are being plotted: vertically or horizontally. I used `facet_wrap()` to produce Fig.1 below (code is in the Reproducible Code section).

However, I would like to be able to produce the plot below (with the strip on "top") using `facet_grid()` not facet_wrap.

Fig.1: I want to be able to plot this using `facet_grid()`

[image: Fig.1]

Ideally, it would be great if the switch argument could be extended or the `strip.position` argument could be added to `facet_grid()`, to be able to place the strip on top. I tried to do it myself by trying to change the source code from `facet_grid()` and `facet_wrap()` functions, but could not figure it out.

The reason I am not simply using `facet_wrap()` function is because it unfortunately does not have the `space="free"` argument which is available in `facet_grid()` and is essential in my application.

Below is a reproducible example taken from, with slight modifications, the code of Brandon Bertelsen answer's [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23207878/ggplot2-group-x-axis-discrete-values-into-subgroups):

**Reproducible Code:**

*The Data:*

```
dat <- data.frame(value=runif(30)*10,
                  grouping=c(rep("Group 1",10),
                             rep("Group 2",10),
                             rep("Group 3",10)),
                  letters=rep(LETTERS[1:10], 3)
```

Using `facet_wrap` to get strip on top when plotting graphs vertically:

```
ggplot(dat, aes(letters,value, label = letters)) + 
  geom_bar(stat="identity") + 
  facet_wrap(grouping~., dir = "v")
```

Produces Fig.1:

[image: Fig.1:]

Using `facet_grid` with the `switch = "y"` places the strip to the left hand side:

```
ggplot(dat, aes(letters,value, label = letters)) + 
  geom_bar(stat="identity") + 
  facet_grid(grouping~., switch = "y")
```

Produces Fig.2:

[image: Fig.2]

Using `facet_grid` with the `switch = "x"` places the strip to the right hand side:

```
ggplot(dat, aes(letters,value, label = letters)) + 
     geom_bar(stat="identity") + 
     facet_grid(grouping~., switch = "x")
```

Produces Fig.3:

[image: Fig.3]

With no other options remaining I turn here for help.

Comment: If you leave `scales = 'free'` out and just do `facet_wrap(grouping~., dir = "v")` you should get what you want.

Comment: Hi @MarBlo thank you for your response. However, this is not my question at all. Perhaps my question was not very clear and I have modified my post. I need to use facet_grid() not facet_wrapt() to produce the plot; scales = 'free' does not help. Is there some way using facet_grid() to produce Fig.1. Thanking you

Comment: This sounds like a version of the [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). What you really want is to have free space on the y-axis while keeping strip titles at the top of each plot, no? Or is there some other reason why you absolutely need to use `facet_grid`? For example, `facet_col` from the `ggforce` package may serve your needs. See discussion [here](https://github.com/tidyverse/ggplot2/issues/2933).

Comment: Thank you @Z.Lin for your comment. Indeed, I do absolutely need to use facet_grid(). I tried facet_col() like facet_wrap() and it does not work for me. I will also change my post and mention facet_col() there for other people. The thing is my visualization is a bit more complex than the toy example I have created for stackoverflow. I will try to convert my code to something reproducible and post how facet_grid looks vs facet_col and facet_wrap look for my visualization. But nonetheless, yes, I do need to use facet_grid() and need to somehow place the strip on the "top" of the plot.

Comment: @FaizanKhalidMohsin, did you find a solution to this problem? I'm facing exactly the same problem as you did.

Comment: @RuamPimentel, Hi, I haven't been able to find a solution as of yet but did post on ggplot2 package manager thread to add to enable this, but have not had a response from them :( unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

ggforce::facet_col() will do this. It's got strip.position argument as well as scales and space arguments

Answer (score -1):

Is that what you want? Then just leave `sales = 'free'` out.

```r
library(ggplot2)

dat <- data.frame(value=runif(26)*10,
                  grouping=c(rep("Group 1",10),
                             rep("Group 2",10),
                             rep("Group 3",6)),
                  letters=LETTERS[1:26])

ggplot(dat, aes(letters,value, label = letters)) + 
  geom_bar(stat="identity") + 
  facet_wrap(grouping~., dir = "v")
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2020-06-13 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: Hi @MarBlo , No this not what I want. My question is how can the above graph be created using facet_grid() with the Group 1, Group 2, Group 3 strips on the top of the plots not using facet_wrap(). Thanking you