# ggplot2 - summarizing date and show time at peaks

Tags: r, dataframe, ggplot2, visualization

Having a dataframe with columns of date, time and the value.

```
    date  time value
1 28.02. 15:19 14.63
2 28.02. 15:30 16.11
3 28.02. 15:41 78.47
4 28.02. 15:51 13.42
5 01.03. 08:12 15.46
6 01.03. 08:23 14.66
7 01.03. 08:34 14.14
8 01.03. 08:45 13.52
```

I want a barchart with a bar for every row. On the x-axis the date should be shown, but summarized for the areas where bars of a date are shown. These areas should be seperated with an vertical line. The time only should be shown on peak bars. High peaks can be defined as >2*mean(value).

[image]

I tried the following. The vline is manually added at that point where the date changes in the dataframe. When i set x to the date column, the bars will be aggregated for the whole date, so i set it to the index.

```
p = ggplot(test, aes(x=1:nrow(test), y = value)) +
    geom_col(fill="#b0bdc7") +
    labs(y="Seconds", x="Run") +
    theme_minimal() +
    theme(panel.grid.major.x = element_blank(), panel.grid.minor.x = element_blank()) +
    geom_hline(aes(yintercept = median(value), color ="#eb6619")) +
    theme(legend.position="none") +
    coord_cartesian(ylim = c(0, 50)) +
    scale_y_continuous(breaks= c(10,20,30,40,50)) +
    geom_vline(aes(xintercept = 5.5), linetype=2, color="#494856")
```

Comment: very, **very** related https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23207878/ggplot2-group-x-axis-discrete-values-into-subgroups/75557978#75557978

Comment: and actually a better thread https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18165863/multirow-axis-labels-with-nested-grouping-variables