# ggplot - Have groups on the x axis for line chart

Tags: r, ggplot2, graph

I have a basic dataframe which shows RMSE per group.

```
data <- data.frame(
  RMSE = c(9.77, 9.6, 9.42, 7.98, 7.78, 7.63, 7.66, 7.65, 7.61, 6.63, 6.58, 6.43),
  Model = c("LR - LHS", "LR - LHS", "LR - LHS", "XGB - Reg", "XGB - Reg", "XGB - Reg",
            "RF - LHS", "RF - LHS", "RF - LHS", "XGB - LHS", "XGB - LHS", "XGB - LHS")
)
```

I want to create a line plot of RMSE, but on the x axis want model 1, 2 and 3, and the group below it. Something like this:

[image: Graph on paper]

What I'm getting is 4 x values, 3 points one below each other, rather than next to each other (with 12 values).
Another plot I tried gave good results, but it was 4 different disconnected lines.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is a way inspired in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75557978/8245406) to another SO question.
Instead of `paste0` the code below uses `interaction` and orders numerically within groups. Then package `ggh4x` ([CRAN](https://CRAN.R-project.org/package=ggh4x), [GitHub](https://github.com/teunbrand/ggh4x)) takes care of grouping the axis labels.

```r
data <- data.frame(
  RMSE = c(9.77, 9.6, 9.42, 7.98, 7.78, 7.63, 7.66, 7.65, 7.61, 6.63, 6.58, 6.43),
  Model = c("LR - LHS", "LR - LHS", "LR - LHS", "XGB - Reg", "XGB - Reg", "XGB - Reg",
            "RF - LHS", "RF - LHS", "RF - LHS", "XGB - LHS", "XGB - LHS", "XGB - LHS")
)

suppressPackageStartupMessages({
  library(dplyr)
  library(ggplot2)
})

data %>%
  mutate(
    Group = interaction(row_number(), Model, sep = "&"),
    Group = factor(Group, levels = stringr::str_sort(Group, numeric = TRUE))
  ) %>%
  ggplot(aes(Group, RMSE, group = Model)) +
  geom_line() +
  geom_point() +
  guides(x = ggh4x::guide_axis_nested(delim = "&"))
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2023-09-08 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

---

I don't see the point of having different colors for each line, it adds noise to the plot with no real new information, the lines are already separated by groups of `Model`.
But here it is anyhow.

```r
data %>%
  mutate(
    Group = interaction(row_number(), Model, sep = "&"),
    Group = factor(Group, levels = stringr::str_sort(Group, numeric = TRUE))
  ) %>%
  ggplot(aes(Group, RMSE, group = Model, colour = Model)) +
  geom_line() +
  geom_point() +
  guides(x = ggh4x::guide_axis_nested(delim = "&"))
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2023-09-08 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

---

## Edit 2

Answering [asd-tm's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77065074/ggplot-have-groups-on-the-x-axis-for-line-chart/77065328#comment135859781_77065328), here is the plot with the numbers within models on the x axis.
The main difference is in the data prep, first coerce `Model` to factor with the appropriate levels, then group by model and only then create the interactions with the (row) numbers within models.

```r
data %>%
  mutate(Model = factor(Model, levels = Model %>% unique())) %>%
  group_by(Model) %>%
  mutate(Group = interaction(row_number(), Model, sep = "&")) %>%
  ggplot(aes(Group, RMSE, group = Model, colour = Model)) +
  geom_line() +
  geom_point() +
  guides(x = ggh4x::guide_axis_nested(delim = "&"))
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2023-09-08 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: Would you like to make a correction. The OP was asking to show not `1:12` but `rep(1:3, 4)` as x axis ticks and breaks (see the picture)